# Crystalreportviewer.processreponse locks mxsqlserver database account with error SSPI handshake exception

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystalreportviewer.processreponse locks mxsqlserver database account with error SSPI handshake exception,

Message 
SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure.

Message 
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Message 
Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue trying to deploy a Web Portal for Crystal Reports and the user that was connecting to the Web Portal via the browser did not have security permissions on the SQL database. For me it was as simple as adding the user to the security tab in the SQL Server management console. You might want to check that out first. If not, please check the steps outlined in this [link](http://dusk1911.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/sql-2008r2-sspi-handshake-failed-with-error-code-0x8009030c/). The troubleshooting steps in the article may help you resolve your issue.The ultimate solution for this user was to check his local security policies to see if any essential rights had been denied. He tried to connect to a share on the server. The connection to a share failed, and he realized the account did not have "access this computer from the network" rights or was missing other domain or network level permissions.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for your reply, Forgot to add an important observation. Few reports which have single table importwed in .rpt files are working but any report which has more then one table imported isnt working

Comment: Are they the same tables? For example, a report with many tables that isn't working, does it have tables in it that are working in a single-table report? (I hope that makes sense!)